# Play different audio files depending on given parameter

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a method that has to play an audio file when a button is pressed. But I want the audio file that has to be played depend on the parameter of the method. The parameter is a int with the same name as the audio file in raw folder. But I noticed that the id in `Mediaplayer.create(this, R.raw.audio)` can't be replaced with the method parameter. What is the right way to approach this problem?

```java
public void playAudioFile(int audioId) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio2);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.start();
            player.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: u just have to pass the audioId directly like this , mediaplayer.create(this,audioId)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you want?

```
playButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        playAudioFile(R.raw.audio1)
    }
});

playButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        playAudioFile(R.raw.audio2)
    }
});

public void playAudioFile(int audioId) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), audioId);
    player.start();
}
```